# Is $\exists x(P(x)\rightarrow\forall y P(y))$ a tautology?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

This is from the book by D.J. Velleman-"How to prove it?" Sec 3.5 Excercise 31:

Prove $\exists x(P(x)\rightarrow\forall y P(y))$

Suppose the universe of discourse is set of all men.

Let statement P(x) $:=$ $x$ is married. Then $\forall yP(y)$ means all men are married. Thus, there exists a man, if his marital status is married that means are all men are married. Am I interpreting the statement correctly? It is not abvious to me why this statement is true at all.

Comment: you might have to disprove it...

Comment: Hmm. How are you going to prove $\exists x(P(x)\to\forall y(P(y))$ considering a specific example? Are you simply trying to figure out how to create a useful linguistic analogue?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox) might be useful.

Comment: @Winther Nice link. Hadn't seen that before; apparently it was popularized by Smullyan. That guy is awesome. Thanks for the link.

Comment: There is a man such that if he is awake, all men are awake.

Comment: Do it by cases. If all men are married, then who can you choose as $x$ to make the statement true? If there is an unmarried man, who can you choose as $x$ to make the statement true?

Comment: Note that, if one of the men marries or divorces, it is entirely possible that $x$ changes. At any given time, there is such an $x$, but it needn't always be the same $x$. (Usually $P(x)$ is a property that doesn't depend on time, though.)

Comment: This is an example of the so-called Drinker's Paradox. A set-theoretic version would be $\exists x:[x\in P \implies Q]$ where $P$ is an arbitrary set, and $Q$ an arbitrary proposition. For a detailed development, see conclusion of "The Drinker's Paradox: A Tale of Three Paradoxes" at my math blog at http://dcproof.wordpress.com/ Note that is *not* necessarily true that $\exists x: [x\in P] \implies Q$.